# How do I attach a picture to ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, grid, png

Im trying to attach a picture (png file) to a geom_line plot in ggplot2. The method I am using is:

```
Data<-read.csv("file.csv",check.names=FALSE)
Pic<-readPNG("pick.png")
PicGrob<-rasterGrob(Pic,interpolate=TRUE)


ggplot(Data,aes(x=`Xdata`,y=value))+annotation_custom(PicGrob,ymin=75,xmin = 1)+
geom_line(aes(y=`Value1`,col="Value1"))+geom_line(aes(y=`Value2`,col="Value2"))+ 
theme(legend.background = element_rect(colour = "black"), legend.position=c(0.8,0.7))+ 
ggtitle("GGtitle")+ylab("Ylabel")
```

When this is entered the following error comes up:

```
>Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'value' not foundError in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'value' not found
```

The plot works fine if the `annotation_custom(PicGrob,ymin=75,xmin = 1)` is omitted.

(The packages ggplot2, png and grid are loaded)

Comment: Can you make your example reproducible? For instance, use `mtcars` dataset and a picture that comes shipped with `R`, for example `system.file("img", "Rlogo.jpg", package="jpeg")`. Please also add `library` calls.

Comment: Add `aes(y = NULL)` in `annotation_custom`. (btw. why do you use backticks insice `aes`?)